# WCF REST services 'unexpected end of file'

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest

I have an ASP.NET web application where i am using WCF  REST services to insert 500  reords but getting the error 'unexpected end of file'  i have put

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <!-- Create a custom binding for our service to enable sending large amount of data -->
    <binding name="NewBinding0" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"   maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>

</bindings>
```

in both client cofig and service config ,but the same issue exists...any solution for this

Answer (score 4):

Solution is probably to stop and search for some articles about WCF and REST and learn at least essentials of the API you are trying to use.

`basicHttpBinding` is for SOAP services, not for REST services. REST services use `webHttpBinding` so it is hard to say what's going on in your application because your very first statement

> I am using WCF REST services

is in direct collision with the rest of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Mrnka is correct, you should be using webHttpBinding for REST. Your web.config file should have this:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
      <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding>
            //binding here
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>

    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address and the default endpoint 
             -->
    </system.serviceModel>
```